# Find candidate key from functional dependancy

Tags: functional-dependencies, candidate-key

For a relation {A,B,C,D} with the following functional dependancies -

```
A -> BCD
B -> C
CD -> A
```

Using a particular method i found on one of the sites, i am getting the candidate key as ABCD. Is that right ? What is the correct candidate key(s) ?

Comment: No, that's not right. In the first place, {ABCD} is the whole relvar, so {ABCD} is a trivial superkey. What method and web site did you follow? What method is in your textbook?

Comment: @Catcall : here's the link..http://www.techvyom.com/forum/Thread-How-to-find-Candidate-Keys..
Is ABCD right according to that ? Or am I missing something ??

Comment: ABCD is a trivial superkey. Every algorithm has to generate ABCD.  But ABCD isn't a candidate key in this relation. (By definition, a candidate key is a *minimal* superkey.) You can tell the algorithm in your link is inadequate by simple inspection. It doesn't generate A as a candidate key, but you're *given* `A -> BCD`. There are two more candidate keys besides A.

Comment: @Catcall : Ohh..!! :/ Do u know where i can find a correct algorithm ?

Comment: Your textbook. Which one are you using?

Comment: @Catcall : Umm..this exactly isnt part of my course-work..its regarding a separate exam that i have to give, and as far as i remember it wasnt done in our course too..

Comment: Every college-textbook I've seen about database systems included at least one algorithm. Let me see what I can link you to online.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ABCD is a trivial superkey. Every algorithm has to generate ABCD. But ABCD isn't a candidate key in this relation. By definition, a candidate key is a minimal superkey.

You can tell the algorithm in your link is inadequate by simple inspection. It doesn't generate A as a candidate key, but you're given A -> BCD, so A is clearly a candidate key. There are two more candidate keys besides A.

[This SO answer by @ErwinSmout](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7788117/562459) describes an algorithm that's suitable for pencil and paper. Most textbooks include algorithms that are suitable for automation.

Answer (score 0):

Lets make it simple:
Here is a definition for **Super,candidate** keys

**Super Keys**

> Super key stands for superset of a key.
>
> A Super Key is a set of one or more attributes that are taken collectively and can identify all other attributes uniquely.

**Candidate Keys**

> Candidate Keys are super keys for which no proper subset is a super key.
>
> In other words candidate keys are minimal super keys.

By **Closure property**,
we get

> **A+=ABCD**

since

> A->BCD **given**
>
> A->A   **reflexivity rule**

Thus A is the Candidate key.

Hope this helps!